# How can I get Merged Cell Range and Next Column Name in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've merged cells C5:Z5. Now I want to get the column Z5 using GAS as the merge cell boundary. And another thing I've tried to get the next column using GAS. For example, the next column of Z is AA. How can I get the next column using GAS.

Comment: Could you please supply a code example?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood,

1. If you want to get the Z5 value after merge, simply copy the  z5 value to c5 before  mergeAcross(). So it saves the z5 value to resulting merge cell.
2. For getting the next column value, you can access the column values as numericals. simply get the last column value and increment it.

Hope that helps!

Comment: You did not understand the problem. None wants the value. Its like something that will merge a new column with existing merged columns. For the second part of the problem, how I can get function_next_cloumn('Z')='AA'.